# select elements in sequence (by group class name)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how do I select elements created dinamicamentes by groups? I want to select `msgpvtstyleme` and work on them. Then select `msgpvtstyle` again and work on them ... Goal is to get grouped elements and insert them classes .....

[image]

I want to simulate chat balloons

[image]

result final! Thank you all!

[image]

Comment: Why does the last `msgpvtstyleme` have `first middle last` classes? Also what happens if there are more than 3 serial elements?

Comment: @Aziz because only he exists in the sequence, then it is the first, middle and last...

Comment: Can u tell us the sequence of adding new classes ?

Comment: @NiharSarkar want to simulate chat balloons...it is unpredictable... this was the idea that I found to simulate chat balloons...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic jQuery script which checks each element and detecting the following:

- Check current `class`
- If previous sibling has a different class then it will get `first`
- If next sibling is of the same class, it will be `middle`
- If next sibling is of another class, it will be marked as `last`
- If previous and next siblings are of other classes, it will be `first middle last`

```js
// define your container here
var container = $('.container'),
    currentClass = container.children(":first").attr("class");

// run through each child
container.children('li').each(function() {
  currentClass = $(this).attr("class");
  
  if ( $(this).prev().attr("class") !== currentClass ) {
   $(this).attr("data-order","first");  }
  
  if ( $(this).next().attr("class") === currentClass && $(this).prev().attr("class") === currentClass ) {
   $(this).attr("data-order","middle");  }
  
  if ( $(this).next().attr("class") !== currentClass ) {
   $(this).attr("data-order","last");  }
  
  if ( $(this).next().attr("class") !== currentClass && $(this).prev().attr("class") !== currentClass ) {
   $(this).attr("data-order","first middle last");  }
  
  // debugging only
  $(this).text( $(this).attr("class") + ': ' + $(this).attr('data-order') );
});
```

```css
li[data-order~="first"] {font-weight: bold;}
li[data-order~="last"] {border-bottom:1px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="class1"></li>
  <li class="class1"></li>
  <li class="class1"></li>
  <li class="class2"></li>
  <li class="class2"></li>
  <li class="class1"></li>
</ul>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/40trqhn4/

**Note:** I used `data-order` attribute instead class as altering the class name will break the checking function (since it all revolves around class name). You can access the elements through the CSS attribute selectors `[data-order="first"]` for example.

Comment: perfect your answer !! thank you so much. Look at the photo I put in my post the final result! Much obliged!

Comment: That's really cool, glad I could help! @blex has a valid answer as well. have a nice day/evening.

Comment: Yes! i saw! I will analyze... tks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way:

```
function style_latest_messages() {
  var classes = '.msgpvtstyle, .msgpvtstyleme';

  $(classes).filter('.first,.middle,.last')
            .last().removeClass('first middle last')
            .add($(classes).not('.first,.middle,.last')).each(function() {
              styleMessage(this);
            });

  function styleMessage(el) {
    var prev = $(el).prevAll(classes).eq(0),
        next = $(el).nextAll(classes).eq(0),
        is_first = is_me(prev) != is_me(el) || !prev.length,
        is_last  = is_me(next) != is_me(el) || !next.length;

    if(is_first) $(el).addClass('first');
    if(is_last)  $(el).addClass('last');
    if(is_first == is_last) $(el).addClass('middle');
  }
}

function is_me(el) { return $(el).hasClass('msgpvtstyleme'); }
```

> Note that `$(this).prevAll(classes).eq(0)` and `$(this).nextAll(classes).eq(0)` will allow you to ignore any extra element, such as time. Try the demo to see what I mean.

### Demo

```js
style_latest_messages();

function style_latest_messages() {
  var classes = '.msgpvtstyle, .msgpvtstyleme';

  $(classes).filter('.first,.middle,.last')
            .last().removeClass('first middle last')
            .add($(classes).not('.first,.middle,.last')).each(function() {
              styleMessage(this);
            });
    
  function styleMessage(el) {
    var prev = $(el).prevAll(classes).eq(0),
        next = $(el).nextAll(classes).eq(0),
        is_first = is_me(prev) != is_me(el) || !prev.length,
        is_last  = is_me(next) != is_me(el) || !next.length;

    if(is_first) $(el).addClass('first');
    if(is_last)  $(el).addClass('last');
    if(is_first == is_last) $(el).addClass('middle');
  }
}

function is_me(el) { return $(el).hasClass('msgpvtstyleme'); }


// Just for testing
var msgs=['<li class="time">17:52</li><li class="msgpvtstyleme">Don\'t forget to unload the dishwasher</li>', '<li class="msgpvtstyleme">Did you finish your homework?</li>', '<li class="msgpvtstyleme">Your grandmother is coming for dinner.</li>', '<li class="msgpvtstyleme">Dad and I decided to buy you a car.</li>', '<li class="time">17:56</li><li class="msgpvtstyle">Did U? OMG thank U!</li>', '<li class="msgpvtstyleme">No I was just making sure you get my texts.</li>', '<li class="msgpvtstyle">That was cruel</li>']; (function add_msg(){if(!msgs.length)return;$('.messagepvt').append(msgs.shift());style_latest_messages();setTimeout(add_msg,(msgs[0] || "").length * 50)})();
```

```css
.messagepvt{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin-left: -35%; list-style: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width: 70%; margin-top: 0; background: #f5f5f5; padding: .5em }body{ overflow: hidden }.messagepvt:after{ content: ""; display: block; clear: both }.time{ text-align: center; clear: both; color: #888; font-size: 10px; margin: .5em }.msgpvtstyle, .msgpvtstyleme { padding: .3em .8em; float: left; clear: both; background: #e6e6ec; color: #000; margin: 1px; font-size: 12px; -webkit-transition: border-radius .25s ease; -moz-transition: border-radius .25s ease; -webkit-animation: deploy .15s ease; -moz-animation: deploy .15s ease; -webkit-transform-origin: top left; -moz-transform-origin: top left }.msgpvtstyle.first { border-radius: 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em .5em }.msgpvtstyle.middle { border-radius: .5em 1.5em 1.5em .5em }.msgpvtstyle.last { border-radius: .5em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em }.msgpvtstyle.first.middle.last, .msgpvtstyleme.first.middle.last { border-radius: 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em }.msgpvtstyleme { float: right; background: #49f; color: #fff; -webkit-transform-origin: top right; -moz-transform-origin: top right}.msgpvtstyleme.first { border-radius: 1.5em 1.5em .5em 1.5em }.msgpvtstyleme.middle { border-radius: 1.5em .5em .5em 1.5em }.msgpvtstyleme.last { border-radius: 1.5em .5em 1.5em 1.5em }@-webkit-keyframes deploy{ from{-webkit-transform: scale(0)}to{-webkit-transform: scale(1)} }@-moz-keyframes deploy{ from{-moz-transform: scale(0)}to{-moz-transform: scale(1)} }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="messagepvt"></ul>
```

Comment: uoww! tks I will analyze! I thank you for your patience!

Comment: nice ideia of time on chat!! ;)

Comment: @FábioZangirolami No problem :) Happy you could find what you wanted with Aziz. I made a first version without the time, and then I saw your image, which has that. That's why I decided to make some changes.

Comment: I'll probably end up using your script because of prevall and nextall, as you say ignore the time .. I will test later. Grateful!

Comment: I ran your script dynamically inserting texts. Checked that this accumulating classes --> `<li class="msgpvtstyleme first last middle"></li>`,
`<li class="msgpvtstyleme last middle"></li>`,
`<li class="msgpvtstyleme last middle"></li>`,
`<li class="msgpvtstyleme last"></li>`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked, it worked 100% !! I will try to compare your solution with the @AZIZ and see which script is faster!

Comment: @FábioZangirolami I must admit, I did not think about that! I fixed it by targeting messages that do not have the `first`, `middle` or `last` class, and by also treating the previous message (because it was `.last`, but now that we added new messages, it might not be anymore). Check that out and see if it works for you. I've also made the demo add messages after a delay to test it.

Comment: Understood! I will test with the new changes... impressive effects that u put in balloons.. nice!!

Comment: only thing I noticed that the effect of source .. the smallest to the biggest one (the transition) .. occurs thickening  in the font but then returns to normal.. but worked 100% with new changes in script!! Good night and good week! ;)

Comment: I put a `li tag` marking time, the script does not consider it .. i need it start again after the tag .. the example of AZIZ does it very well!

Comment: `Note that $(this).prevAll(classes).eq(0) and $(this).nextAll(classes).eq(0) will allow you to ignore any extra element, such as time. Try the demo to see what I mean.` i changed nextall and prevall to next and prev!! worked 100% gracias!!

Comment: I have several chats. I needed to pass the dynamically created element! not fixed it only in `var class = '.msgpvtstyle, .msgpvtstyleme';` because that affects all chat windows that have the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to add classes in existing html tags

```
$('.msgpvtstyle ').each(function() {
  $('.msgpvtstyleme:first-child' , $(this)).addClass('first');
  $('.msgpvtstyleme:last-child' , $(this)).addClass('last');
  $('.msgpvtstyleme:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)' , $(this)).addClass('middle');
});
```

Comment: `$('ul.messagespvt').each(function() {
    $('.msgpvtstyleme:first-child' , $(this)).addClass('first').removeClass('last');
    $('.msgpvtstyleme:last-child' , $(this)).addClass('last');
    $('.msgpvtstyleme:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)' , $(this)).addClass('middle').removeClass('last');
  });`

Comment: @NiharSarkar You did right! However I will wait for other answers .. I need to avoid the 'loop' add new classes only where there is still no ...

Comment: U need to use loop because u don't know the total number of `ul` elements .

Comment: This script does not work properly and will mark the very last element as `.last` without considering serial groups.

Comment: @NiharSarkar Thanks for listening! Look at the photo I put in my post the final result!